# JScrollPane: Adjust scroll position after increasing the font size of the inner text

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane, jquery-jscrollpane

I am increasing the font size of the inner text. After increasing the font size how can I maintain scroll position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you increasing the inner text? through the browser's font-size options, or through an interaction?

http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/scroll_to.html

You could use scroll_to to change the position as you alter the font size...

Answer (score 2):

You could also use 'maintainPosition - boolean (default true)

Whether the scrollpane should attempt to maintain it's position whenever it is reinitialised. If true then the viewport of the scrollpane will remain the same when it is reinitialised, if false then the viewport will jump back up to the top when the scrollpane is reinitialised.'

Source: http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/settings.html